# JSP IE6 detection

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, jsp

I know you can detect whether your browser is IE or not using the following JSP code:

```
request.getHeader( "User-Agent" );
```

But is there anyway I can detect whether it is IE6 or not?

Comment: Why is it you think you need to know?  It is typically better to offer the browser a number of content types and have it use whichever best suits it.  Any other reason for querying that particular aspect of the end user environment?  What feature does this provide to the end user?

Comment: I am populating some UI data (chart) based on the users browser. For IE6, since the UI support is poor I want to tell the backend about it using a flag

Comment: IE 6 ? Did I just age backwards for 10 years ?

Comment: Yes u did. you need to learn the fact that there are still many important customers using ie6

Comment: It's not always talked about in polite company, but server-side device detection is a valid approach to dealing with devices with limited capabilities.  Pains me a great deal to do anything to make someone with IE6 feel like they are important, but if you had to make this work...

Comment: you ll get surprised if you know what companies are still using this ie6 phenomenon. Thanks anyway man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this list](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) it looks like the magic string you are looking for is

```
"MSIE 6."
```

So this should work for you:

```
boolean is_IE6 = user_agent.indexOf("MSIE 6.") > -1;
```

Or put all together in JSP:

```
<% boolean is_IE6 = request.getHeader("user-agent").indexOf("MSIE 6.") > -1;
   if(is_IE6) { %>
  Some IE 6 Thing
<% } else { %>
  Some non IE 6 Thing
<% } %>
```

There is a "more correct way" of doing this (politely called server-side device detection) with a library called [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).  WURFL uses an expanding database of user-agents and device capabilities and lets you respond to a HTTP Request based on the device making the request with code like this (taken from their [documentation of the Java API](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava_index.php)):

```
WURFLHolder wurfl = (WURFLHolder)getServletContext().getAttribute(WURFLHolder.class.getName());

WURFLManager manager = wurfl.getWURFLManager();

Device device = manager.getDeviceForRequest(request);

log.debug("Device: " + device.getId());
log.debug("Capability: " + device.getCapability("preferred_markup"));

MarkUp markUp = device.getMarkUp();

String jspView = null;

if (MarkUp.XHTML_ADVANCED.equals(markUp)) {
  jspView = XHTML_ADV;
} else if (MarkUp.XHTML_SIMPLE.equals(markUp)) {
  jspView = XHTML_SIMPLE;
} else if (MarkUp.CHTML.equals(markUp)) {
  jspView = CHTML;
} else if (MarkUp.WML.equals(markUp)) {
  jspView = WML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>    
// IE 6 detected    
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I am looking for the JSP solution

Comment: @ComeRun: you tag your question with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code,

```
        if(/msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
            alert("IE 6"); 
        }
```